# Panel Autoscroll Maximum Value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, panel, autoscroll

I create Form and I add Panel with Autoscroll is true;

After than , I Add this code;

```
Int32 _y =0;
progressBarX1.Maximum = 600;


for (int i = 0; i <= 600;i++ )
{
    progressBarX1.Value = i;
    ButtonX _btn = new ButtonX();
    _btn.Click += new EventHandler(_btn_Click);
    _btn.Width = 100;
    _btn.Visible = true;
    _btn.Height = 70;
    _btn.Text = i.ToString();
    _btn.Left = 0;
    _btn.Top = _y;
    _y += 80;
    panel1.Controls.Add(_btn);
}
```

I run the project, but in Panel I see just 407 button, I can not move down with vscroll. All rest buttons doesnt show in panel. But the code is add button to panel. And I check with Tab and buttons are there. The problem Panel Scrolling are I think. Max Height is 32500 aproxilamte. So Vscroll down max this 32500 value.

How Can I increase the Autoscroll Height area ?

Answer (score 2):

The autoscroll are is not the issue.

Unfortunately the maximum location for a control is 32767 for either x or y.
So the panel is drawing all the buttons on top of each other at the highest location.

If you call BringToFront on the last button, it will become visible.