# Picture Box and Panel in Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, image, panel, picturebox

I need to display 100 images one below the other in the form.

I followed the below idea:

Added a panel to the Form and in code I added 100 picture box and assigned each picture box with the image I have.
Now the problem is I can see only 32 picture box.
Why? Any property need to be updated...?
Below is my code :

```
List<int> bottomlist = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    PictureBox pic = new PictureBox();
    Image img = //I get image by some code here//
    pic.Image = img;
    pic.Size = img.Size;
    if (i == 0)
        bottomlist.Add(pic.Bottom + 8);
    else
        bottomlist.Add(pic.Bottom + bottomlist[i - 1] +8);
    if (i == 0)
        pic.Top = 8;
    else
    {
        pic.Top = bottomlist[i - 1] + 8;
    }
    pic.Left = (panel1.ClientSize.Width - pic.Width) / 2;
    panel1.Controls.Add(pic);
}
```

Comment: i think its about memory

Comment: @developerCoder-- OK I will try by clearing the image in the top when i scroll down.

Comment: both your if's are on i==0, why not combine them

Comment: Did you enabled AutoScroll in panel?

Comment: @Sayse yes, i kept a break point and checked... it iterated 100 times

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yes, it is enabled

Comment: After the loop try this `MessageBox.Show(panel1.Controls.Count.ToString);`  to know how many controls it have

Comment: @SriramSakthivel it shows 100 frnd

Comment: Seems like windows limitation Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499368/winforms-maximum-size-of-a-control-is-65535-workaround) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175807/panel-autoscroll-maximum-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i took your code and ran it and got a similar problem to yours: i only saw 8 images.

then i remembered that panels need to manually define `AutoScroll` to true otherwise it just looks like i have less images. now i can see them all:

[image]

the code is same as yours, the only added is

```
     this.panel1.AutoScroll = true;
```

if you need to resize the pictures, try [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922040/resize-an-image-c-sharp). it basically saying to do:

```
public static Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
{
   return (Image)(new Bitmap(imgToResize, size));
}

yourImage = resizeImage(yourImage, new Size(50,50));
```

Comment: Frnd, I set Autoscroll to true, but all my image is having height of 1056px

Comment: so you have a lot to scroll? @UthistranS. i'm trying to understand what are you asking

Comment: yeah.! thats it... you used some iceon size image above, i am using 860*1056 each of 100

Comment: then you need to shrink them, that's a whole different question, lemme google that @UthistranS.

Comment: if you want to show 100 huge pictures, i would suggest you start by showing only 10 at a time and let the user move to another page when he passed 10 @UthistranS.